# How to add a line to a stacked bar chart with grouped labels?

Tags: apexcharts

I try to create an ApexChart which will display a mixed chart (line and stacked column). this chart has also grouped labels. But I do not know how to add a line series to this chart? If I add a new sereis as type line- the line will not appear on the chart. I google the whole day and ask Bing Copilot for help- without a usable result.
Thanks for your help.
Marius

Here is my code without the line series:

```js
var options = {
  series: [
    {
      name: "Typ 1",
      data: [
        {x: 'Früh', y: 200},
        {x: 'Spät', y: 215},
        {x: 'Nacht', y: 224},
        {x: 'Früh', y: 235},
        {x: 'Spät', y: 270},
        {x: 'Nacht', y: 290},
      ]
    },
    {
      name: "Typ 2",
      data: [
        {x: 'Früh', y: 200},
        {x: 'Spät', y: 215},
        {x: 'Nacht', y: 224},
        {x: 'Früh', y: 235},
        {x: 'Spät', y: 270},
        {x: 'Nacht', y: 290},
      ]
    },
    {
      name: "Typ 3",
      data: [
        {x: 'Früh', y: 200},
        {x: 'Spät', y: 215},
        {x: 'Nacht', y: 224},
        {x: 'Früh', y: 235},
        {x: 'Spät', y: 270},
        {x: 'Nacht', y: 290},
      ]
    }
  ],
  chart: {
    type: 'bar',
    height: 380,
    stacked: true, 
  },
  xaxis: {
    type: 'category',
    labels: {
      formatter: function(val) {
        return val
      }
    },
    group: {
      style: {
        fontSize: '10px',
        fontWeight: 700
      },
      groups: [
        { title: 'Montag', cols: 3 },
        { title: 'Dienstag', cols: 3 }
      ]
    }
  },
  title: {
    text: 'Grouped Labels',
  },
};

var chart = new ApexCharts(document.querySelector("#chart"), options);
chart.render();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Chart</title>

</head>
<body>
    <div id="chart"></div>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/apexcharts"></script>
</body>
</html>
```